# Как правильно сделать запрос, SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь сделать добавление данных из формы поиска на сайте в базу mysql.

Создал таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE `dle_search` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `story` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Добавляется так. Здесь `$story` это и есть данные из формы поиска.

```
$db->query( "INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "_search (story) values ('$story')" );
```

Как сделать чтобы не было дублей. Получается так

```
id | story

1 | текст

2 | текст

3 | текст
```

По идее `id` мне вообще не нужен, но без него у меня не получилось, чтобы можно было эти поля(1-2-3) удалять по отдельности.

Comment: *По идее id мне вообще не нужен* Ну так выбросите это поле из структуры, а на `story` создайте уникальный индекс - дубликаты добавиться тупо не смогут...

Comment: Вот это и не получается CREATE TABLE `dle_search` ( `story` varchar(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`story`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

Comment: Ну какой автоинкремент для строки??? удалите эти два слова.

Comment: Теперь не дублируется, но появляется ошибка при одинаковом поиске Duplicate entry 'текст' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Ну а с чего бы ей НЕ появляться? Делайте INSERT IGNORE, а не просто INSERT.

Comment: так обработайте ошибку. если БД вернула duplicate - то можете честно сообщить пользователю что такая запись уже есть или как то по другому отреагировать на эту ситуацию

Comment: Пользователю это сообщать не зачем, он должен свободно пользоваться поиском, а дублирование хочется убрать. И зря я `id` убрал, без него не поймёшь последний запрос. Так, что вопрос открыт. Нужно и `id` оставить и чтобы дубли не добавлялись.

Comment: Добавил UNIQUE KEY `story` (`story`), после PRIMARY KEY (`id`), теперь нормально, не дублируется.